# Combining machine name, model, mac, and serial into a formatted csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm super new to Powershell and am trying to take the name, model, serial number, and mac address of multiple computers and put them into a CSV for viewing in Excel. I already have the computer's recording their info in txt files that output as so:

```
Name
COMPUTER1
Model
EXAMPLE MODEL
SerialNumber
ABC123
=================== ======================================================
00-00-00-00-00-00   \Device\Tcpip_{00000000000000000000}
```

I've been trying to figure out a way to take this info from multiple files, all formatted in this identical manner, and combine them all into a single CSV with the column heads Name, Model, Serial Number, Mac Address. I tried concatenating them into one file removing extra titles and adding the column names to the top but I can't get past the carriage returns screwing up my formatting. Here's what I have right now

```
$file = select-string -path .\test*.txt -pattern null -NotMatch | select line
$file | foreach-object {
    $_.line = $_.line.replace("=","")
    $_.line = $_.line.replace("Name","")
    $_.line = $_.line.replace("Model","")
    $_.line = $_.line.replace("Physical Address","")
    $_.line = $_.line.replace("Transport Name","")
} 
$file | export-csv .\combinedText.csv -NoTypeInformation
$csv = get-content -path .\combinedText.csv
$csv = $csv -replace "line","Model`",`"Serial Number`",`"MAC Address"
$csv | set-content .\combinedText.csv -passthru | set-content .\combinedText.txt
```

here is the txt output

```
"Model","Serial Number","MAC Address"
""
"YAVINIV"
""
"To Be Filled By O.E.M."
"SerialNumber"
"To Be Filled By O.E.M."
" "
"D0-50-99-6B-FD-64   \Device\Tcpip_{8008113C-6231-4393-B2F6-08EC9D64EE24}"
""
"YAVINV"
""
"Test"
"SerialNumber"
"Test"
"    Transport "
" "
"D0-50-99-6B-FD-62   Media disconnected"
```

Comment: Since you want to write your data in a .csv format you should just write a single line for each entry with a delimiter between the values.

Comment: I realize you are processing from these flat text files at this time. A very posh thing to do would be to script the commands that gather this information and use `Invoke-Command` to run it on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic example but i think it will do what you ask given that the data file is always the same format...

You can then add a loop for multiple files.

```
$mydatafile = Get-Content d:\test.txt

New-Item d:\test -type directory -Force
New-Item d:\test\data.csv -type file -Force

$header = $mydatafile[0] + ";" + $mydatafile[2] + ";" + $mydatafile[4] + ";" + "MAC-Address"
Add-Content -path d:\test\data.csv $header

$dataentry = $mydatafile[1] + ";" + $mydatafile[3] + ";" + $mydatafile[5] + ";" + $mydatafile[7]
Add-Content -path d:\test\data.csv $dataentry
```

Output will look like this

```
Name;Model;SerialNumber;MAC-Address
COMPUTER1;EXAMPLE MODEL;ABC123;00-00-00-00-00-00   \Device\Tcpip_{00000000000000000000}
```

You can trim the stuff off the MAC address in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are countless PowerShell ways to do this, here is one with Select-String and -Context parameter:

```
$Csv = @()
Get-ChildItem Test*.txt | Select-String Name -Context 0,7| ForEach {
   $Csv += [PSCustomObject]@{
      'Name'         =   $_.Context.PostContext[0]
      'Model'        =   $_.Context.PostContext[2]
      'SerialNumber' =   $_.Context.PostContext[4]
      'MacAddress'   =   $_.Context.PostContext[6].Substring(0,17)
      'TransportName'=   $_.Context.PostContext[6].Substring(20)}
}
$Csv | Format-Table -Auto
$Csv | Out-GridView
$Csv | Export-CSV .\combinedText.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Choose one or more from the `Format-Table` / `Out-GridView` / `Export-Csv` cmdlets

Sample output

```
Name      Model                  SerialNumber           MacAddress        TransportName
----      -----                  ------------           ----------        -------------
COMPUTER1 EXAMPLE MODEL          ABC123                 00-00-00-00-00-00 \Device\Tcpip_{00000000000000000000}
YAVINIV   To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M. D0-50-99-6B-FD-64 \Device\Tcpip_{8008113C-6231-4393-B2F6-08E...
COMPUTER1 EXAMPLE MODEL          ABC123                 00-00-00-00-00-00 \Device\Tcpip_{00000000000000000000}

> Get-Content .\combinedText.csv
"Name","Model","SerialNumber","MacAddress","TransportName"
"COMPUTER1","EXAMPLE MODEL","ABC123","00-00-00-00-00-00","\Device\Tcpip_{00000000000000000000}"
"YAVINIV","To Be Filled By O.E.M.","To Be Filled By O.E.M.","D0-50-99-6B-FD-64","\Device\Tcpip_{8008113C-6231-4393-B2F6-08EC9D64EE24}"
"COMPUTER1","EXAMPLE MODEL","ABC123","00-00-00-00-00-00","\Device\Tcpip_{00000000000000000000}"
```